# Fast calculation of partial sums on a large SQL Server table

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, sum, aggregate-functions

I need to calculate a total of a column up to a specified date on a table that currently has over 400k rows and is poised to grow further. I found the `SUM()` aggregate function to be too slow for my purpose, as I couldn't get it faster than about 1500ms for a sum over 50k rows.

Please note that the code below is the fastest implementation I have found so far. Notably filtering the data from `CustRapport` and storing it in a temporary table brought me a 3x performance increase. I also experimented with indexes, but they usually made it slower.

I would however like the function to be at least an order of magnitude faster. Any idea on how to achieve that? I have stumbled upon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree. However, I would rather have the storage and calculation processed within SQL Server.

`CustRapport` and `CustLeistung` are Views with the following definition:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CustLeistung] AS 
SELECT TblLeistung.* FROM TblLeistung 
WHERE WebKundeID IN (SELECT WebID FROM XBauAdmin.dbo.CustKunde)

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CustRapport] AS 
SELECT MainRapport.* FROM MainRapport 
WHERE WebKundeID IN (SELECT WebID FROM XBauAdmin.dbo.CustKunde)
```

Thanks for any help or advice!

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getBaustellenstunden] 
(
    @baustelleID int,
    @datum date
)
RETURNS 
@ret TABLE 
(
    Summe float
)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @rapport table
    (
        id int null
    )

    INSERT INTO @rapport select WebSourceID from CustRapport 
    WHERE RapportBaustelleID = @baustelleID AND RapportDatum <= @datum

    INSERT INTO @ret
    SELECT      SUM(LeistungArbeit)
    FROM CustLeistung INNER JOIN @rapport as r ON LeistungRapportID = r.id 
    WHERE LeistungArbeit is not null 
         AND LeistungInventarID is null AND LeistungArbeit > 0

    RETURN 
END
```

Execution plan:

http://s23.postimg.org/mxq9ktudn/execplan1.png

http://s23.postimg.org/doo3aplhn/execplan2.png

Comment: Please add what indexes you have on tables CustLeistung and CustRapport. Also, how many records are you inserting into your table variable?

Comment: What is the datatype of `RapportDatum`? Is it `date`? i.e. has no time component?

Comment: `RapportDatum` is `datetime`

Comment: Please provide the definition of the function `Portal_common_MyKundeUser` as it appears to be messing up the optimizer here.  Also `CusteKunde` appears to be a view as well, so we need that definition too.

Comment: For people still coming here today: [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) from 2012 points to `SUM()` + `OVER()` + `ROWS` as a *very* fast method

Answer (score 1):

General advice I can provide now until you provide more information.

Updated my query since it was pulling from views to pull straight from the tables.

```
INSERT INTO @ret
    SELECT
        SUM(LeistungArbeit)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT WebID FROM XBauAdmin.dbo.CustKunde
    ) Web
    INNER JOIN dbo.TblLeistung ON TblLeistung.WebKundeID=web.webID
    INNER JOIN dbo.MainRapport ON MainRapport.WebKundeID=web.webID 
        AND TblLeistung.LeistungRapportID=MainRapport.WebSourceID
        AND MainRapport.RapportBaustelleID = @baustelleID
        AND MainRapport.RapportDatum <= @datum
   WHERE TblLeistung.LeistungArbeit is not null 
   AND TblLeistung.LeistungInventarID is null
   AND TblLeistung.LeistungArbeit > 0
```

1. Get rid of the table variable. They have their use, but I switch to temp tables when I get over a 100 records; indexed temp tables simply perform better in my experience.
2. Update your select to the above query and retest performance
3. Check and ensure there are indexes on every column references in the query. If you use the show actual execution plan, SQL Server will help identify where indexes would be useful.

Comment: Regarding point one `#temp` tables can't be used in functions (though I see your proposed rewrite doesn't use them anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is hovewer only about half as fast as my initial solution. The problem with this solution seems to be the expensive RapportDatum <= @datum compairson executed too often

Comment: @RobinBruegger Please try my updated query. Also, please post the indexe definitions on the tables